# aAccessing key values in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON response like this. I want to access the `rollbacktoken` key. How should I do it ?

```
{"query":{
    "pages":{
        "5":{
            "pageid":5,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Abhishek",
            "revisions":
              [{
                "revid":376,
                "parentid":360,
                "user":"Abhishek",
                "timestamp":"2015-02-15T10:29:55Z",
                "comment":"",
                "rollbacktoken":"232e77d570434db159dbbd3d43d3ea4e+\\"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
var a = JSON.stringify(query.pages.revisions.rollbacktoken);
```

Answer (score 4):

figured it out 
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(json.query.pages['5'].revisions['0'].rollback);

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
json.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("pages")..getJSONObject("5").getJSONObject("revisions").rollbacktoken;
```

Comment: what about the integer key " 5 " in the JSON obj

Comment: try `console.log(json.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("pages")..getJSONObject("5").getJSONObject("revisions").rollbacktoken);`